# Sorting numbers in QTableWidget work doesnt right Pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

There are column with numbers only. But it sorts like that:

[image: sort with my wrong code]

And how this part of code looks like:

```
self.table = QTableWidget(self)  
self.table.setColumnCount(5)     
self.table.setRowCount(0)       
self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.table.sortByColumn(1, Qt.DescendingOrder)
```

And there are not just 4 or 5 rows, it cant be 10,100, or more, because i have a button to insert row with custom number in this 1st column. And some buttons to edit items in this column (but it still only numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insert the item data as text strings, they will always use the alphanumerical ordering, so numbers from 1 to 20 will be sorted like this:

```
1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 4, ...
```

To achieve numerical ordering, the data has to be stored as numeric, and this can be done by using [`setData(role, value)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData):

```
from random import randrange
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
# ...
    def addData(self):
        for row in range(10):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, randrange(10000))
            self.table.setItem(row, 1, item)
```

Alternatively, you can subclass the QTableWidgetItem, as shown in this answer: [Sorting in pyqt tablewidget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11941099).

Comment: I believe this solution holds if all the number involved are non-negative integer [0, ∞). In other words, if string's `.isnumeric()` method returns `True`. If there is a number that is a float or a negative number, than you need to create a subclass of `QTableWidgetItem`.

Comment: @mak this solution does **not** use strings. Types are not altered when set on the model, if `setData` is used with integers or floats (as in my answer), sorting will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Now I see that **calling QTableWidgetItem's empty constructor is important**. In other words, **this works:** `item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()` but **this doesn't work** `item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(floatString)` even though `item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, float(floatString))` is called afterwards (in both of the above cases).

Comment: @mak interesting. It seems that the problem resides in the way QTableWidgetItem sets the data: it checks the existing value of the item and compares using the [QVariant `==` operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#operator-eq-eq), which also checks if the type can be converted. Since a numeric string can be converted to a number, the result is that `"-5" == -5`, and the new value is not set because it thinks it's the same. It seems that the same happens for QListWidget and QTreeWidget, and I believe it can be considered a bug.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it can be considered a bug. I am new to PyQt5 and I really do not know well enough to judge. So I am very grateful for your response. If you are willing, then can you report the bug and let me know its tracking number (so that in the future, when I know PyQt5 well enough, I will know where to report)? PS: I seem to have a knack in running into bugs since I am new. The other day [I ran into a bug in Perl](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s107/nl/11689221/ae88772a-d8ba-41f6-bf0e-6b95c2cf6d7a).

Comment: What if the string has numbers and I want to sort it just like that? Example: "Data1", "Data20", "Data3".

Comment: @AkrashNadeem Then in that case you need to do the sorting on your own, possibly implementing a custom QTableWidgetItem subclass.

Comment: @musicamante Do you have any example about it

Comment: @AkrashNadeem See this question: [How to customize sorting behaviour in QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48496311).

Comment: `DisplayRole` is now under `ItemDataRole` (`QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole`)

Comment: @Raymo111 that's imprecise. The original syntax is still perfectly valid for PyQt5 (and "allowed" in *forgiveness* mode in PySide6) which is the target of the OP. The new naming standard is mandatory since PyQt6 (as it will be in PySide at some point) because of the introduction of actual Python enums, so it requires using the full namespace for **any** Qt enum, not just `DisplayRole`, nor `ItemDataRole` only or even the `Qt` namespace alone.

Comment: Ahh I see, doesn't this still mean that doing ``QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole` is better?